# Checking if the 'block' has unique pattern

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a file with number of 'blocks' (three blocks in this example) that look like this:

```
A4_RAT  Amyloid-beta A4 protein;    P08592  PDB; 1M7E; X-ray; 2.45 A; D/E/F=755-763.
                                    PDB; 1NMJ; NMR; -; A=672-699.
                                    PDB; 1OQN_I3P.pdb; X-ray; 2.30 A; C/D=755-763.
                                    PDB; 2LI9; NMR; -; A/B=672-687.

AACP_AGRFC  Aminoacyl carrier protein;  A9CHM9          PDB; 2JQ4; NMR; -; A=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2W_5GP.pdb; X-ray; 1.95 A; C/D=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2X_G5A.pdb; X-ray; 2.15 A; C/D=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2Y; X-ray; 2.10 A; C/D=1-83.

AADB1_KLEPN 2''-aminoglycoside nucleotidyltransferase;  P0AE05  PDB; 4WQK; X-ray; 1.48 A; A=1-177.
                                    PDB; 4WQL; X-ray; 1.73 A; A=1-177.
                                    PDB; 5KQJ_GOL.pdb; NMR; -; A=1-177.
```

Each 'block' has `PDB;`, `XXXX/XXXX_XXX.pdb;`, `Xray/NMR;` columns. From the last two columns from the previous sentence (`XXXX;` or `XXXX_XXX.pdb;` and `X-ray; or NMR;`) there are several options that I am encountering within each block:

`XXXX;` `X-ray;`
`XXXX_XXX.pdb;` `X-ray;`
`XXXX;` `NMR;`
`XXXX_XXX.pdb;` `NMR;`

I am trying to search only for those 'blocks' that have only `XXXX_XXX.pdb; X-ray;` and only for those 'blocks' that have only `XXXX_XXX.pdb; NMR;`.

From the example here, if I do the search for those that have only `XXXX_XXX.pdb; X-ray;` I am expecting result to be:

```
A4_RAT  Amyloid-beta A4 protein;    P08592  PDB; 1M7E; X-ray; 2.45 A; D/E/F=755-763.
                                    PDB; 1NMJ; NMR; -; A=672-699.
                                    PDB; 1OQN_I3P.pdb; X-ray; 2.30 A; C/D=755-763.
                                    PDB; 2LI9; NMR; -; A/B=672-687.

AACP_AGRFC  Aminoacyl carrier protein;  A9CHM9          PDB; 2JQ4; NMR; -; A=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2W_5GP.pdb; X-ray; 1.95 A; C/D=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2X_G5A.pdb; X-ray; 2.15 A; C/D=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2Y; X-ray; 2.10 A; C/D=1-83.
```

On the other hand, if I do the search for those that have only `XXXX_XXX.pdb; NMR;` I am expecting result to be:

```
AADB1_KLEPN 2''-aminoglycoside nucleotidyltransferase;  P0AE05  PDB; 4WQK; X-ray; 1.48 A; A=1-177.
                                    PDB; 4WQL; X-ray; 1.73 A; A=1-177.
                                    PDB; 5KQJ_GOL.pdb; NMR; -; A=1-177.
```

Does anybody has idea how to do it in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming you have empty lines between each block as you show in your question, so:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/...._...\.pdb; NMR;/' RS= infile
AADB1_KLEPN 2''-aminoglycoside nucleotidyltransferase;  P0AE05  PDB; 4WQK; X-ray; 1.48 A; A=1-177.
                                    PDB; 4WQL; X-ray; 1.73 A; A=1-177.
                                    PDB; 5KQJ_GOL.pdb; NMR; -; A=1-177.
```

---

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/...._...\.pdb; X-ray;/' RS= infile
A4_RAT  Amyloid-beta A4 protein;    P08592  PDB; 1M7E; X-ray; 2.45 A; D/E/F=755-763.
                                    PDB; 1NMJ; NMR; -; A=672-699.
                                    PDB; 1OQN_I3P.pdb; X-ray; 2.30 A; C/D=755-763.
                                    PDB; 2LI9; NMR; -; A/B=672-687.
AACP_AGRFC  Aminoacyl carrier protein;  A9CHM9          PDB; 2JQ4; NMR; -; A=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2W_5GP.pdb; X-ray; 1.95 A; C/D=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2X_G5A.pdb; X-ray; 2.15 A; C/D=1-83.
                                    PDB; 4H2Y; X-ray; 2.10 A; C/D=1-83.
```

To preserve the empty lines remove `RS=` and add statement `{print $0"\n"}`:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/...._...\.pdb; NMR;/{print $0"\n"}' infile
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/...._...\.pdb; X-ray;/{print $0"\n"}' infile
```